# using playwright inside electron window with nodeIntegration option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, playwright

code for frontend react js

```
import { chromium } from 'playwright';

export default function App() {
  const createBrowser = async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });

    const context = await browser.newContext();

    const page = await context.newPage();

    const element = await page.waitForSelector('.products', {
      state: 'visible',
      timeout: 5,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={createBrowser}>
        CreateBrowser
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Error

[image]

I'm using electron Electron-React-boilerplate template
in electron options i'm using **nodeIntegration** option to run node js api in frontend and it works find with node js api

but when i try to get any element using **page.waitForSelector** or **page.locator('input')** or **page.fill** or **page.click** thorw this error how can i get playwright fully working with react js at fronted I don't want to use ipcMan to send request to nodejs from frontend to run test

Answer (score 0):

do you want to test the UI ? if so i wrote an answer here [Electron desktop Application testing with[PLAYWRIGHT]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72695873/electron-desktop-application-testing-withplaywright/73375269#73375269).

after you init the project, and write the tests you simply use npx playwright tests.

also did you try to load the page with a url, maybe the page is not loading any html file and this is why it doesn't work

Comment: I think the correct command is `npx playwright test`. Asking for clarification seems more like a comment than an answer, in any case.